# Problem with a static directional light following a rotating object and/or the camera movement

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader

I am struggling to set a day-night cycle with a directional light in a Earth model by using custom shaders. The night and day maps as well as the light are ok as long as I do not touch the camera, i.e., the Earth rotates as the light source remains still and nights and days are updated correctly. However, when I rotate the camera using the mouse, the light appears to follow the the camera, so you always see an illuminated part of the Earth.

This is how I set the light source:

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(5,3,5);
scene.add(light);
```

This is how I pass the parameters to the shader:

```
uniforms_earth = {
    sunPosition: { type: "v3", value: light.position },
    dayTexture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "daymap.jpg" ) },
    nightTexture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/nightmap.jpg" ) }
};
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
varying vec2 v_Uv;
varying vec3 v_Normal;

uniform vec3 sunPosition;
varying vec3 v_vertToLight;

void main() {

    v_Uv = uv;
    v_Normal = normalMatrix * normal;

    vec4 worldPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    v_vertToLight = normalize(sunPosition - worldPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * worldPosition;

}
```

And this the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D dayTexture;
uniform sampler2D nightTexture;

varying vec2 v_Uv;
varying vec3 v_Normal;

varying vec3 v_vertToLight;

void main( void ) {

    vec3 dayColor = texture2D(dayTexture, v_Uv).rgb;
    vec3 nightColor = texture2D(nightTexture, v_Uv).rgb;

    vec3 fragToLight = normalize(v_vertToLight);

    float cosineAngleSunToNormal = dot(normalize(v_Normal), fragToLight);


    cosineAngleSunToNormal = clamp(cosineAngleSunToNormal * 10.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    float mixAmount = cosineAngleSunToNormal * 0.5 + 0.5;

    vec3 color = mix(nightColor, dayColor, mixAmount);

    gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );

}
```

Finally, I use the THREE library for the camera controls:

```
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
```

And I update the Earth rotation inside the render function as:

```
function render() {
    controls.update();
    earth.rotation.y += rotation_speed; 
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I have already tried to change how I compute `v_vertToLight` so that both the vertex and the light position are in the same world as:

```
v_vertToLight = normalize((modelViewMatrix*vec4(sunPosition, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz);
```

This stops the light from moving when I change the camera, but then, the night-day shadow remains always in the exact same place as the light appears to start rotating with the Earth itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call `worldPosition` is not a position in world space, it is a position in view space. Rename the misnamed variable:

<s>`vec4 worldPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);`</s>

```c
vec4 viewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

`sunPosition` is a position in world space. It has to be transformed to view space, before it can be used to calculate the view space light vector. This has to be done by the `viewMatrix` rather than `modelViewMatrix`. Note, the `modelViewMatrix` from model space to view space and the `viewMatrix` transforms from worlds space to view space (see [three.js - WebGLProgram](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram)):

```c
vec4 viewSunPos = viewMatrix * vec4(sunPosition, 1.0);
v_vertToLight = normalize(viewSunPos.xyz - viewPosition.xyz);
```

Note, `v_vertToLight` and `v_Normal` both have to be either view space vectors or world space vectors, the have to have the same reference system. Otherwise it would not make sense to calculate the dot product of both vectors.

Vertex shader:

```c
varying vec2 v_Uv;
varying vec3 v_Normal;

uniform vec3 sunPosition;
varying vec3 v_vertToLight;

void main() {

    vec4 viewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 viewSunPos   = viewMatrix * vec4(sunPosition, 1.0);

    v_Uv = uv;
    
    v_Normal      = normalMatrix * normal;
    v_vertToLight = normalize(viewSunPos.xyz - viewPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
}
```

See the very simple example, which uses the vertex shader:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var loader, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls, mesh;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -4);
    //camera.lookAt( -1, 0, 0 );

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();

  }

  function createModel() {

    var uniforms = {
          u_time : {type:'f', value:0.0},
          u_resolution: {type: 'v2', value: {x:2048.,y:1024.}},
          u_color : {type: 'v3', value: {x:1.0, y:0.0, z:0.0} },
          sunPosition : {type: 'v3', value: {x:5.0, y:5.0, z:5.0} }
    };
        
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(0, 0, -1);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.131/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.131/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
varying vec2 v_Uv;
varying vec3 v_Normal;

uniform vec3 sunPosition;
varying vec3 v_vertToLight;

void main() {

    vec4 viewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 viewSunPos   = viewMatrix * vec4(sunPosition, 1.0);

    v_Uv = uv;
    
    v_Normal      = normalMatrix * normal;
    v_vertToLight = normalize(viewSunPos.xyz - viewPosition.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
}
</script>
<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
precision highp float;
uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
varying vec2 v_Uv;
varying vec3 v_Normal;
varying vec3 v_vertToLight;
uniform vec3 u_color;
void main(){
    float kd = max(0.0, dot(v_vertToLight, v_Normal));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color.rgb * kd + 0.1, 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: By doing what you said, the light does no longer move with the camera but then, the light rotates with the planet itself. Also, the light changes with the camera zoom, I don't know why...

Thanks for your answer Rabbid.

Comment: @Gabriel Oh sorry. I was sloppy, but somehow you were tricking me. I got confused by the name `worldPosition`. Anyway, I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid75 I see where the confusion comes from. I'm sorry, your are right. Now it is working like a charm and your explanation makes all sense. Thanks again for your answer and for your time.